# Render 2 outputs referencing the same data set

Tags: r, shiny

I built the shiny app below that updates the line graph based on the user's input. It works fine until I try to generate a 2nd output. How can I display the value `total.weight` calculated in the `renderPlot()` function? It seems to me my data set `df` and the variable `total.weight` should be created "outside" of the `renderPlot()` function but I have not figured out how.

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Reproducible Example"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("ID", "group", c("A", "B"))
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1"),
      verbatimTextOutput("text1")
    )
  )
))
```

**server.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    years <- c(1:10)
    weight <- c(5,7,9,11,12,17,19,20,21,22)
    group <- c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5))
    df <- data.frame(years,weight,group)

    df <- subset(df, group == input$ID)
    total.weight <- sum(df$weight)

    #Plot
    ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df$years, y=df$weight)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point() 



  })

  output$text1 <- renderText({total.weight})

})
```

**Output snapshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also create  reactives:

server.R

```
library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

            df <- reactive({
                    years <- c(1:10)
                    weight <- c(5,7,9,11,12,17,19,20,21,22)
                    group <- c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5))
                    df <- data.frame(years,weight,group)

                    df <- subset(df, group == input$ID)

            })

            total.weight <- reactive({
                    sum(df()$weight)
            })

            output$plot1 <- renderPlot({




                    #Plot
                    ggplot(data=df(), aes(x=years, y=weight)) +
                            geom_line() +
                            geom_point() 



            })

            output$text1 <- renderText({total.weight()})

    })
```

Comment: what is being assigned to `df` with the `reactive()` function exactly? Is it years, weight, group, or df?

Comment: It is df in your case, usually the variable in the last line of code. To be sure I often put just the variable name that I want to assign as the last line of code. This mean that in df() the columns are years, weight & group.

Answer (score 1):

The quick workaround is to put the total weight in a global varaiable:

```
total.weight <<- sum(df$weight)
```

The nice way to do it is to subset your data.frame within a `reactive` function:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    years <- c(1:10)
    weight <- c(5,7,9,11,12,17,19,20,21,22)
    group <- c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5))
    df <- data.frame(years,weight,group)

    reactive_df <- reactive(subset(df, group == input$ID))

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data=reactive_df(), aes(x=years, y=weight)) +
        geom_line() +
        geom_point() 
    })

    output$text1 <- renderText({sum(reactive_df()$weight)})

})
```